# Create a generic function wrapper that works for all function types

Tags: c

I would like to be able to wrap any function in a big system with a function that will insert few statements before and after the wrapped function. These added statements will serve a special purpose such as timing the function execution or print a debug a message or anything of that sort.

The wrapper does not have to absolutely one and only one function (or macro), but if more than one is needed, they should be kept to minimum in count.

To better explain what I would like to do here is an example:

Existing code:

```
void my_big_function(void) {
     int data1;
     int data2;
     int ret1;
     fun1();
     ret1 = fun2();
     anotherfun3(data1);
     myfun4();
     awesomefun5(data2);
}
```

This need to be changed to :
void run_and_time

```
run_and_time(void* fun_p, void* retval, ... )
{
         // statements before calling the function (e.g. get current time)
         // call the function and give it the parameters it needs.
         // statements After calling the function (e.g. get new time and subtract start time from it)

}

void my_big_function(void) {
         run_and_time(&fun1, NULL);
         run_and_time(&fun2, &ret1);
         run_and_time(&anotherfun3, NULL, data1);
         run_and_time(&myfun4, NULL);
         run_and_time(&awesomefun5, NULL, data2);
}
```

This needs to be done in Standard C.

UPDATE:
There are environments where you can not run a profile to time or even debug function calls. For example consider the boot up process in the Linux kernel for an embedded system. In such cases, tool chains might not be maintained to a high and useful level.

To propose something to start with, we can look at the start_kernel function in the Linux kernel. In that function, there is a series of calls to functions of type `void f(void)`. For this type of functions that is easy. Here is an abstract example of what can be done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef MY_DEFINITION
#include <sys/time.h>

#define time_func_call(x, y) do { \
struct timeval  tv1, tv2; \
gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL); \
x(); \
gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL); \
printf ("%s took %lu micro seconds to finish\n", y, (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec)   + \
       (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) * 1000000); \
\
} while (0)
#else
#define time_func_call(x, y) do { \
x();\
} while (0)
#endif



void good_function(void){
    printf("Inside good_function\n");
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    time_func_call(good_function, "good_function");
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And here is a test run:

```
$ gcc -o ./test ./main.c 
$ ./test 
Inside good_function
$ gcc -o ./test -DMY_DEFINITION ./main.c 
$ ./test 
Inside good_function
good_function took 51 micro seconds to finish
```

Now, that works for that particular type of functions. But can we extend that to function with other signatures?

Comment: Why on earth did you tag this "c++11" if it needs to be "done in standard C"??!

Comment: *"This needs to be done in standard C."* - Then why tagging C++ and C++11?

Comment: Removed the C++ tags. Also, I am a little confused as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: With use of `_Generic` and macro magic, a limited solution is available, yet post is unclear.  Post sample timing functions, and sample `fun1, fun2, fun3` signatures.

Comment: Sounds like an awful idea. If you want to profile your functions, use the features of your tool-chain.

Comment: `#define WRAP(statement) do { prefix(); statement; postfix(); } while(0)` ? with usage `WRAP(fun1();); WRAP(ret1 = fun2(););`

Comment: @Olaf I want this for an environment where I can not run profiling tools.

Comment: @chux I want to this be as generic as possible. So, if I posted specific code, the answer will be tailored for that code. And this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: By posting your best solution and then pointing out its shortcomings, your coding goal would be more clear.  With "as generic as possible" and lacking timing issues, the goal is too broad.  Example concerns, could the functions nest?  `timed_foo()` calls `timed_bar()`--> what is the expectation?  What about threads? Many other issues too that would be narrowed with better examples.

Comment: @chux I see your point. The question did not mention anything about thread safety...so assume it is thread unsafe. timed_foo() is not supposed to call timed_bar.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think you need to elaborate your very promising proposal. It seems to be ignored.

Comment: Why are you bent on making code unreadable?  Difficult to debug? Goal cannot profile it. Thought about shoot yourself in the head?

Comment: Why so mean? Anyways, I would sacrifice a subjective goal such as "readable code" to get a concrete goal "able to debug and profile my code"